How to force SWIG to see DECLSPEC preprocessor macro when included from another file?
I am using SWIG version 4.0.2 in a Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL) Ubuntu distribution.  I am attempting to create a Python extension module that wraps a C++ library.  The C++ library is intended to used in both Windows and Linux environments, and thus its classes and external functions are decorated with a __declspec for Windows, and nothing for Linux, via the following well-known preprocessor macro, which is in a common types.h header file that is included in many other header files in the C++ library.
types.h
#pragma once

#if defined( WIN32 )
  #ifdef FOO_EXPORT
    #define FOO_DECLSPEC __declspec(dllexport)
  #else
    #define FOO_DECLSPEC __declspec(dllimport)
  #endif
#else
  #define FOO_DECLSPEC
#endif

I am only interested in the Linux environment.  Thus FOO_DECLSPEC will be blank.
When SWIG generates its C++ wrapper code, it behaves as if it does not understand that FOO_DECLSPEC is a preprocessor macro.  Instead, it treats it as the name of a class.  The result is that the generated C++ wrapper code is wrong and will not compile.  The following is a simplified example that demonstrates the problem.
The simple C++ library to wrap can be represented by the following header file.  It includes types.h, which defines FOO_DECLSPEC.
example3.h
#pragma once

#include "types.h"

class FOO_DECLSPEC Person
{
private:
  int m_id;

public:
  Person( void )
  : m_id( 42 )
  {
  }

  virtual ~Person( void )
  {
  };

  int getID( void ) const
  {
    return m_id;
  }
};

The SWIG interface file I use to generate the C++ wrapper code is the following.
example3.swg
%module example3

%{
#define SWIG_FILE_WITH_INIT
#include "example3.h"
%}

%include "example3.h"

The command line I use to generate the C++ wrapper code is the following.
finch@laptop:~/work/swig_example$ swig -c++ -python -v example3.swg
Language subdirectory: python
Search paths:
   ./
   ./swig_lib/python/
   /usr/share/swig4.0/python/
   ./swig_lib/
   /usr/share/swig4.0/
Preprocessing...
Starting language-specific parse...
Processing types...
C++ analysis...
Processing nested classes...
Generating wrappers...

There are no errors indicated in the SWIG output.  However, the generated example3_wrap.cxx file is wrong and will fail to compile. For example, the first thing wrong is in the types table.  It thinks the class name is FOO_DECLSPEC instead of Person.
example3_wrap.cxx (wrong result)
...
* -------- TYPES TABLE (BEGIN) -------- */

#define SWIGTYPE_p_FOO_DECLSPEC swig_types[0]
...

A kludge change to source to avoid wrong result
In contrast, if I define FOO_DECLSPEC in example3.h, instead of including types.h, then the generated C++ wrapper code is correct and will compile.
example3.h (with kludge change)
#pragma once

// DO NOT INCLUDE THIS   #include "types.h"

// DEFINE FOO_DECLSPEC HERE INSTEAD
#if defined( WIN32 )
  #ifdef FOO_EXPORT
    #define FOO_DECLSPEC __declspec(dllexport)
  #else
    #define FOO_DECLSPEC __declspec(dllimport)
  #endif
#else
  #define FOO_DECLSPEC
#endif

class FOO_DECLSPEC Person
{
  ...
};

example3_wrap.cxx (correct result)
...
* -------- TYPES TABLE (BEGIN) -------- */

#define SWIGTYPE_p_Person swig_types[0]
...

What is the proper fix?
In the actual C++ library I am attempting to wrap, it would be untenable to define the FOO_DECLSPEC macro in every header file it is needed.
Is there something I can do in the SWIG interface file so that SWIG will correctly see the FOO_DECLSPEC preprocessor macro for what it is, when that macro is defined in a separate header file?

%define FOO_DECLSPEC in the .i file. Or, %include "types.h" explicitly. SWIG doesn’t follow nested includes

Thanks @MarkTolonen.  %including types.h worked.

Now that I am wrapping the actual, more complex C++ library, it seems that it is not exactly the case that SWIG does not follow nested includes.  SWIG does pick up types (typedefs, classes, etc) that are defined in nested includes.  It just does not correctly expand... or whatever the proper term is... the preprocessor macros in nested includes.

#include picks up nested includes...that's part of the compile process.  %include tells SWIG to generate the interop language wrappers in that specific header only and does not process items in nested includes (typedefs, prototypes, classes, etc.).  Put a function in a nested include and it won't be exposed as a wrapped function unless %include is used on the nested header.

Note there is a command line option that will process nested includes, but it is usually not desired as you don't want every function in stdio.h for example to be wrapped and exposed to the target language.

Ahhh.   Does that mean that I can use a #include instead of %include in the main part of SWIG interface file, and it will generate wrappers for nested headers?

No, #include is only written in %{ %} section and is added to the generated wrapper to be compiled.  SWIG does nothing with it.
